# How can I transfer multiple frames from the Arducam's fifo buffer to file without zero padding?

Tags: spi, sd-card

I've been unable to resolve a coding problem I've been having with the Arducam Mini 2MP and I was hoping someone might be willing to give me some pointers or clear up any apparent misconceptions I've had regarding the cameras capabilities.

I have my loop setup so the camera captures an image and following this, a lux measurement is taken. If lux exceeds a specified threshold, the image is transferred to an SD card. If not, then fifo is flushed and start_capture is returned to zero.

What I'd like to have is a series of say 3 images, leading up to the point in time when lux exceeds the threshold.

I can buffer more than one frame by writing to the Arduchip registry
    (myCAM.write_reg(ARDUCHIP_FRAMES. 0x03);

The tricky part for me has been transferring multiple buffered images to the SD card. After multiple attempts, I was able to save the images. However, only the first image from the series is viewable. The remaining images, when opened with a hex editor contain a varying number of zeros before the FFD8, causing them to be unrecognizable as jpegs).

This is the code in its entirety, complete with some debugging techniques I was fortunate to stumble upon while trying to resolve the issue (serial printing an asterisks after each 256 byte transfer really helped to develop some understanding of how the SPI transfer was being achieved).

```cpp
// Logs a lux reading and time stamp at approximately ___ms intervals
// 1. three image frames are acquired
// 2. A lux reading and corresponding time of reading is written to the log
// 3. If lux exceeds threshold, the log is closed and the three buffered images are written to the SD card,
// 4. If lux does not exceed threshold, the buffer is wiped
// Image file names indicates the time at which the log was closed and order of image acquisition
// lux readings resume when images are saved (within __s of last lux reading)
// Note: flush command have been removed to speed up sampling rate. lux readings are written to SD when the buffer is full (some data at end will be lost)

#include <SD.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <ArduCAM.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include "memorysaver.h"
#include "RTClib.h"
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include "Adafruit_TSL2591.h"
#if defined(__arm__)
#include <itoa.h>
#endif

/* SPI (Serial Peripheral Interface) synchronous  serial communications interface. */
/* CS (chip select) or SS (slave select)- command pin which enables or disables slave device access to shared I/Os */
const int chipSelect = 10;     // pin 10 is the SS for the SD-card
const int SPI_CS = 23;         // SPI slave select for Arducam
ArduCAM myCAM(OV2640, SPI_CS); // instruct the arducam that its SS is SPI_CS which we just defined as pin 23

float LUX;
char charFileName;
int q;
int k;
unsigned long T;
volatile uint32_t length;

RTC_DS1307 RTC;                                // define Real Time  Clock
File logfile;                                  // logging file
Adafruit_TSL2591 tsl = Adafruit_TSL2591(2591); // the sensor identifier

#define ECHO_TO_SERIAL   1           // zero shuts off serial output
#define WAIT_TO_START    1           // Wait for serial input in setup()

void configureSensor(void)
{
 tsl.setGain(TSL2591_GAIN_LOW);    // 1x gain (bright light)
 tsl.setTiming(TSL2591_INTEGRATIONTIME_100MS); 
}

void stamp()
{
  if (! logfile) {
    logfile = SD.open("test.csv", FILE_WRITE);
  }
  DateTime now;
  now = RTC.now();                  // fetch the time
  logfile.print(now.month(), DEC);
  logfile.print("-");
  logfile.print(now.day(), DEC);
  logfile.print("-");
  logfile.print(now.year(), DEC);
  logfile.print("__");
  logfile.print(now.hour(), DEC);
  logfile.print(":");
  logfile.print(now.minute(), DEC);
  logfile.print(":");
  logfile.println(now.second(), DEC);
}

void setup()
{
  uint8_t vid, pid;
  uint8_t temp;
  Wire.begin();
  Serial.begin(115200);

  #if WAIT_TO_START
    Serial.println("Type any character to start");
    while (!Serial.available());
  #endif //WAIT_TO_START

  Serial.println("ArduCAM Start!");

  pinMode(SPI_CS, OUTPUT);            // set the SPI_CS as an output.
  SPI.begin();                        // initialize SPI
  myCAM.write_reg(ARDUCHIP_TEST1, 0x55);  // is ArduCAM SPI bus is OK
  temp = myCAM.read_reg(ARDUCHIP_TEST1);
  if (temp != 0x55)
  {
    Serial.println("SPI interface Error!");
    while (1);
  }

  myCAM.rdSensorReg8_8(OV2640_CHIPID_HIGH, &vid);
  myCAM.rdSensorReg8_8(OV2640_CHIPID_LOW, &pid);
  if ((vid != 0x26) || (pid != 0x42))
    Serial.println("Can't find OV2640 module!");
  else
    Serial.println("OV2640 detected");

  myCAM.set_format(JPEG);   
  myCAM.InitCAM();
  myCAM.write_reg(ARDUCHIP_FRAMES,0x03);  //Number of frames to captured

  //Initialize SD Card
   if (!SD.begin(10, 11, 12, 13))
  {
    //while (1);        //If failed, stop here
    Serial.println("SD Card Error");
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("SD Card detected!");
  }

  if (!RTC.begin()) {
    Serial.println("RTC failed");
  }

  if (tsl.begin())
  {
    Serial.println("Found a TSL2591 sensor");
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("No sensor found ... check your wiring?");
    while (1);
  }

configureSensor();
stamp();
}

void loop()
{
 acquire();
 k=0;
}

void acquire(){ 
  char str[8];
  File outFile;
  byte buf[256];
  static int i = 0;
  uint8_t temp, temp_last;
  uint8_t start_capture = 0;
  int total_time = 0;
  start_capture = 1;
  if (start_capture)
  {
myCAM.flush_fifo(); // reset the fifo read pointer to 0 (clear the camera buffer?) 
myCAM.clear_fifo_flag(); //clears flag before next capture command
myCAM.start_capture();
  }

  while (!myCAM.get_bit(ARDUCHIP_TRIG , CAP_DONE_MASK));  // what does "CAP_DONE_MASK" mean? Seems like this does nothing. "Polling the capture done flag". Why?
//determine ambient light intensity
uint32_t lum = tsl.getFullLuminosity();
uint16_t ir, full;
ir = lum >> 16;
full = lum & 0xFFFF;
LUX = tsl.calculateLux(full, ir);
T = (millis());
if (! logfile) {
logfile = SD.open("test.csv", FILE_WRITE);
}
#if ECHO_TO_SERIAL
      Serial.print (T); Serial.print(" ");
      Serial.print(LUX); Serial.println("  ");
#endif //ECHO_TO_SERIAL
      logfile.print(" "); logfile.print(T); logfile.print(" ");
      logfile.print(" "); logfile.print(LUX); logfile.println(" ");
    // Did is suddenly get very bright? If it did, retrieve the last series of frames so we can figure out what's going on in this environment.
    if (LUX > 10000) {
    logfile.print ("threshold_exceeded_"); logfile.print (T); logfile.println ("_ms");
    Serial.print ("threshold_exceeded_"); Serial.print (T); Serial.println ("_ms");
    logfile.close();
    length = myCAM.read_fifo_length();
    Serial.print("The fifo length is :");
    Serial.println(length, DEC);

         for  (int q=0; q<3; q++)
          { transfer();
          }      
      /* Clear the capture done flag */
        myCAM.clear_fifo_flag();
      /* Clear the start capture flag. */
        start_capture = 0;
          }
    }

void transfer(){
char str[8];
File outFile;
byte buf[256];
static int i = 0;
uint8_t temp, temp_last;
int total_time = 0;

  //Construct a file name
    k = k + 1;
    String fileName = String();
    fileName = T;
    fileName += "_";
    fileName += k;
    fileName += ".jpg";
    char charFileName[fileName.length() +1];
    fileName.toCharArray(charFileName, sizeof(charFileName));
    outFile = SD.open(charFileName, O_WRITE | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC);
  if (! outFile)
  {
    Serial.println("open file failed");
    return;
  }
  Serial.print("Writing to: ");
  Serial.println(charFileName);

            total_time = millis();
            i = 0;
            myCAM.CS_LOW();
            myCAM.set_fifo_burst();
            temp = SPI.transfer(0x00);
            Serial.print ("temp= "); Serial.println(temp,HEX);
          /* Read JPEG data from FIFO  to temp until the final memory address is reached. */
        while ( (temp != 0xD9) | (temp_last != 0xFF))
        {
          temp_last = temp;
          temp = SPI.transfer(0x00);
        length--;       
      /* Write image data to buffer if not full. The buffer can hold 256 bytes of data. Increment through the cells of the buffer, adding the data from temp until the buffer is full. */
          if (i < 256)
            buf[i++] = temp;
          else
          {
      /* Write 256 bytes image data to file. */
            myCAM.CS_HIGH();
            Serial.print("*");    // each time 256 bytes of data is written to the file, serial print an "*"
            outFile.write(buf, 256);
            i = 0;
            buf[i++] = temp;
            myCAM.CS_LOW();
            myCAM.set_fifo_burst();
          }
        }
        Serial.print("finished (?) temp=0x");Serial.print(temp,HEX);Serial.print(" temp_last=0x");Serial.println(temp_last,HEX);
      /* Write the remain bytes in the buffer */
        if (i > 0)
        {
          myCAM.CS_HIGH();
          outFile.write(buf, i);
        }
      /* Close the file. */
        outFile.close();
        total_time = millis() - total_time;
        Serial.print("Total time used:");
        Serial.print(total_time, DEC);
        Serial.println(" ms");


    Serial.print("The fifo length is :");
    Serial.println(length, DEC);
    }
```

Can someone recommend a way to avoid writing these anomalous 0x00 into my jpeg images?